# Reaction Key module in python3

Tags: python-3.x, keyboard

I am currently working on a project that requires key tracking. I am looking for a module that will record your keystrokes and then the program will react to it: such as

```
if key ('A') is hit
print('hello world')
```

Please redirect me if needed.

**P.S.** (as some background information, I work on Mac 0SX(sadly) also this program is also going to be working with pyautogui to control typing and mouse movements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a library called *getkey*, which allows to read single key events.

```
from getkey import getkey, keys

while (key := getkey()) != 'q':
   if key == 'A':
      print("Hello, World!")
   elif key == keys.ESC:
      print("You can escape by pressing 'q'")
   else:
      print("Key not implemented")
```