# How do I make a function execute when a certain key is pressed?

Tags: python

I am currently using Visual Studio Code as my IDE, and I have been trying to figure out how to make it in my scripts where if a certian key -such as "l" for our example- was pressed, the script would trigger a block of code that executed a function - such as the print("Ayy you pressed a key! good job!") function. I was wondering if anyone could tell me how to do that, or how to make the import keyboard work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reaction Key module in python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62246867/reaction-key-module-in-python3)

Comment: if you run GUI program then you can `bind` key to function. If you mean to run code without (active) GUI then you have modules like `keyboard` or `pynput`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `keyboard` library. Try this:

```
import keyboard

while True:
    if keyboard.read_key() == "p":
        myfunction()
```

Answer (score 0):

As answered in other questions, responding to a key press involves dealing with events.

Each key press triggers/ emits an event. There are couple of library that deals with events and in particular keyboard events.

modules `keyboard` and `getKey` are worth exploring. and to a straightforward answer, refer above answer.(just dont want to repeat, credit to him)